# Loading jQuery and jQuery plugin script files correctly

Tags: plugin-development, jquery

I am using a ticker jQuery plugin and having trouble loading my script files correctly. If I add the scripts in directly into the theme's `header.php` file my scripts work correctly.
Example:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-ticker.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/site.js"></script>
```

If I try to load the scripts from a WordPress plugin I receive an error.
Plugin code:

```
function bbc_frontend_script() {
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('ticker', plugins_url("/js/jquery-ticker.js", __FILE__));
wp_enqueue_script('js', plugins_url("/js/site.js", __FILE__));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bbc_frontend_script' );
```

The error I receive is the console outputs that in`site.js`

```
Uncaught Reference error:Jquery is not defined .
```

Can you please help me understand why I am getting the console error when loading the scripts from a WordPress plugin?

Comment: Once you are loading the scripts correctly (via Rachel Baker's answer), I would wager that the errors are coming from the actual code in the jquery-ticker.js and site.js scripts.... which would tend to make this off-topic (ie: more jQuery-related than WordPress-related)

Comment: @helgatheviking  I should add jQuery.noConflict(); and this solve the problem .thank you

Comment: Close-voted as **too localized**. The jQuery no-conflict issue has been asked and answered several times at WPSE.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `jquery` script as a dependency for your `jquery-ticker.js` and `site.js` files within the `wp_enqueue_script` function.

Example:

```
function bbc_frontend_script() {
wp_enqueue_script('ticker', plugins_url("/js/jquery-ticker.js", __FILE__), array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script('sitejs', plugins_url("/js/site.js", __FILE__), array( 'jquery', 'ticker' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bbc_frontend_script' );
```

You also don't have to enqueue `jquery` separately if you define it as a dependency.

**Edited:**
Added missing `)` at end of enqueue statements.

Comment: thank you .but I am getting error :object has no method ticker

Comment: Where are you getting the error message? Is it a Javascript error or a PHP error?

Comment: I apologize I missed an ) within the code.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Jquery error.Object has no method......

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include your relevant jQuery script that is generating the error (along with the exact error message).

Comment: My bad I was avoiding jquery conflict.........................so placing jQuery.noConflict();  solve the problem..thank you @Chip Benner

Answer (score 1):

Check your examples. You are using plugins_url, but on your other example you say they are in the template directory.

Where are these js files actually located?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the scripts but also define them to the jQuery library e.g.

```
  wp_register_script('ticker', plugins_url("/js/jquery-ticker.js", array('jquery'), '1.3', true );
  wp_enqueue_script('ticker');
```

The array registers it after jQuery is loaded and the true is to set it to register in wp_footer and not wp_head

Comment: You don't need to register them first. You can enqueue them directly with `wp_enqueue_script()`.